# Posting variable to ajax script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I got a function which displays an amount of products depending on a value that is selected in a dropdownlist. This is done with ajax, but for everything to work correctly I need to pass a variable.

On my **catalog.php** I got:

```
$pid = $productcatcr[0]['id'];
```

Which contains the page id.

On the same page I got the dropdownlist:

```
<select class="form-control showcount" name="showcount" id="showcount">
    <option value="100" selected>Alle</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
</select>
```

Which works like this in **ajax.js** :

```
$("#showcount").on('change', function() {

    $.post("ajax/getproducts.php", {start: ($("#showcount").val() - 4), end: $("#showcount").val()}, function(result){
        $("#productviewajax").html(result);
    });
});
```

Finally in **getproducts.php** I use the following query:

```
$product = "SELECT * FROM `web_content` WHERE `catid` = ".$conn->real_escape_string($_GET['id'])." AND state = 1 order by ordering LIMIT ".$_POST['end']."";
```

I need to post id from the initial page, through ajax to the query. What would be the best way to do this? My ajax is not very good.

I got another filter on the initial page on which I can just pass the variable in an url, but the other option element doesn't work like that.

**Example:**

```
<option value="highlow" data-post-url="prijshooglaag.php?id='.$pid.'">Prijs: Hoog naar laag</option>
```

Comment: From Where `$_GET['id']` you got?

Comment: @NanaPartykar Nowhere, That's why I'm asking how to get it posted there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one `hidden input` with class name as pageId (not mandatory with same class name, but if you are changing class name here. Change in Ajax code `id:$(".pageId").val()` here too. Both are related.)

**catalog.php**

```
<?php

$pid = $productcatcr[0]['id'];
?>

<input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $pid;?>' class='pageId'>

<select class="form-control showcount" name="showcount" id="showcount">
  <option value="100" selected>Alle</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="16">16</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
</select>
```

Use `pageId` to get current page id. And, pass it to **getproducts.php** page.

**Ajax**

```
$("#showcount").on('change', function() {
    $.post("ajax/getproducts.php", {start: ($("#showcount").val() - 4), end: $("#showcount").val(),id:$(".pageId").val()}, function(result){
        $("#productviewajax").html(result);
    });
});
```

**getproducts.php**

Instead of `$_GET['id']` use `$_POST['id']` as `$.post` being used in AJAX.

```
$product = "SELECT * FROM `web_content` WHERE `catid` = ".$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['id'])." AND state = 1 order by ordering LIMIT ".$_POST['end']."";
```

Comment: A hidden input inside the select element? Will it automatically get posted if I select a value?

Comment: Not inside `select`. Use before that select dropdown. @twan. Some where in that page either below select dropdown or above.

Comment: @twan: see my updated answer. Don't miss a single thing here. You will succeed.